# Zpool attach to create mirror

Tags: mirror, zfs

I have a 1 TB data disk (no boot data) created in the past, with a snapshot history.

I want to add a disk to create a mirror, but it fails:

```
zpool attach -f zfs-samba /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EVDS-63U8B0_WD-WCAV55352645  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EARX-00N0YB0_WD-WMC0T0284638
```

> cannot attach /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EARX-00N0YB0_WD-WMC0T0284638 to /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EVDS-63U8B0_WD-WCAV55352645: new device has a different optimal sector size; use the option '-o ashift=N' to override the optimal size

Strange is, after this command the new disk (`sdc`) is now a `zfs` member:

```
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID

sdb             931,5G                      
├─sdb9              8M                      
└─sdb1 zfs_memb 931,5G            zfs-samba 4660143235353326727

sr0              1024M                      
sdc             931,5G                      
├─sdc9              8M                      
└─sdc1 zfs_memb 931,5G            zfs-samba 4660143235353326727
```

`sdb` is the existing disk. `sdc` is the new disk, which contained no `zfs`.

From `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EA14D367-371A-114C-8270-19C3E3F51C2C

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953507327 1953505280 931,5G Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdb9  1953507328 1953523711      16384     8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EC89D16E-80B5-0A44-8167-7D60AEBB16C4

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953507327 1953505280 931,5G Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdc9  1953507328 1953523711      16384     8M Solaris reserved 1
```

I tested these actions with file disks, then it works.

I am afraid to damage `sdb`, must be very careful.

What am I doing wrong? Must I first "prepare" `sdc`? I could not find anything about it.

Comment: Please use markdown to format your post correctly/readably.

Answer (score 2):

Found it.
The original disk was created under Solaris. This os version used a sector size=512 (==ashift=9).
I was now working on Ubuntu which defaults to a zfs sector size=4 (==ashift=12). 
So I had to add -o ashift=9, and then it works.